# Twilio for WA messages not being send

Tags: javascript, twilio, whatsapp

Im following the next [tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/use-twilio-sandbox-for-whatsapp) for sending WA and I see the messages on my conversation in the TW console, but I dont seem to receive them on the WA phones as the tutorial shows in the images, like user 1 communicating with user2. Is anything more that I should do in order for the messages to be shown on both users ends?

Comment: I just followed the tutorial and it worked for me. Do you see the outbound message in the log as well? If so, what's the status of that message?

Comment: I do see the messages on the conversation, but checking the message status I get status failed with code 63015 and that error means Channel Sandbox can only send messages to phone numbers that have joined the Sandbox, which is weird because I did the join for both phone numbers that appear on the conversation

Comment: I see what may be happening, on the SB console I see that the number is +521XXXXXXXXXX and on the conversation when looking at the message sent the number is +52XXXXXXXXXX without the one, but how can this be happening, when attaching the number to the conversation I'm sending it as  --messaging-binding.address whatsapp:+521XXXXXXXXXX, copy and pasted the number as it appears on the SB console participants

Comment: Can you confirm that you joined the sandbox channel in the past 24 hours? Maybe the messaging session already auto closed.

Comment: Yes the numbers appeared in there, and I just did that again just to make sure, here are the [link](https://postimg.cc/ygYShYp9)`numbers` on the SB, the  [link](https://postimg.cc/WtxwVgfH)`messages`. and the  [link](https://postimg.cc/YhqmLxy9)`error` on one message

Comment: Can you please use another image hosting service with less ads? SO usually uses https://imgur.com/

Comment: sorry for that on my end dont see any ads, but [here](https://imgur.com/a/ror9i6d) are the images on imgur

Comment: I did more tests with numbers from the US, Argentina and Venezuela and with all of them worked! The issue seems to be only for Mexican numbers where its adding a "1" after the country code

Comment: This is really strange. I tested it only with a German number, so I couldn't reproduce it. I would recommend to open a support ticket as this seems to be a case for them.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. Apparently, there was a change on Mexico numbers that before it was +52 + [1] + [number], and right now it is only +52 + [number] so there is an inconsistency. Anyway thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone that gets the same error, the issue here is on their end, at least for Mexico numbers, when the user sends the message to join the WhatsApp sandbox, Twilio gets the phone number with this format 52 + 1 + [10 dig].  But the correct format is 52 + [10 dig] to send the message. So they never get sent. Lets